# File data not being read processing

Tags: processing

I am absolutely stuck, my file data is not being read in processing using loadStrings();. I have tried everything. Here is my code:

**Main Class**

```
Student[] studentList;
String[] fileData;

void loadFileData(){
  fileData = loadStrings("StudentData.txt");
}

void setup(){
  loadFileData();
  studentList = new Student[fileData.length/3];
  for(int i = 0; i < fileData.length/3; i++){
    studentList[i].studentName = fileData[i];
    studentList[i].studentAddress = fileData[i+1];
    studentList[i].studentNumber = parseInt(fileData[i+3]);
  }
  printArray(fileData);
}
```

**Student Class**

```
class Student{
  String studentName;
  String studentAddress;
  int studentNumber;
  
  Student(String name, String address, int number){
    studentName = name;
    studentAddress = address;
    studentNumber = number;
  }
}
```

My file directory is exactly as follows:

```
>Processing
   >data
      >StudentData.txt
   >student
   >studentSearch
```

All of the data is formatted in lines, name, address, number, repeat

Thank you!

Comment: What is the problem? Do you get an error or just no data? What shows up when you do `printArray`? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hello! I get a nullPointerException referring to the fileData array. It seems like its just not writing the data to the array.

Comment: In the future please post more details about your problem (what is the error, where does it occur, what have you tried in order to narrow down the issue). I had to run your code to see for myself. You might also find that the process of narrowing down the problem in order to explain it leads you to the solution on your own.

Answer (score 0):

I copied your code and ran it here in Processing.
I get a `NullPointerException` on this line:

```
studentList[i].studentName = fileData[i];
```

But it's not being caused by the `fileData` array. You can see this if you print the array immediately after it's loaded. The data is there:

```
fileData = loadStrings("StudentData.txt");
printArray(fileData);
```

You get an error because you're trying to access a `Student` object that doesn't exist. You create an array to hold the objects, but you don't actually put any objects in it before trying to access them in your loop. So `studentList[i]` is null.

You can pass the data directly to your Student constructor when you create the object:

```
studentList[i] = new Student(fileData[i], fileData[i+1], parseInt(fileData[i+3]));
```